# How to get Resharpers InspectCode to recognize Plugins?

Tags: plugins, resharper, command-line-interface, code-inspection

I am trying to run ReSharpers command line tool InspectCode.exe. It's running fine doing it's job with the expected output.

However after my [earlier attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585352/how-to-use-the-stylecop-plugin-with-the-resharper-command-line-or-inspectcode) to get plugins to work, this time with the new version it is supposed to be supported. There is a switch in the command line interface that allows to specify the extension you want to use.

> /extensions (/x) – allows using ReSharper extensions that affect code analysis. To use an extension, specify its ID, which you can find by opening the extension package page in the ReSharper Gallery, and then the Package Statistics page. Multiple values are separated with the semicolon.

But I cannot get it to work properly. I cannot even provoke *any* reaction to the /x switch at all. No matter how or what I pass, I get no feedback from the executable and the output is identical. I don't even get an error message when passing obvious garbage.

I tried the following commandlines for the exact same result:

`inspectcode.exe /o="rcli.xml" /swea /x="ReSharper.StyleCop" "my.sln"`

`inspectcode.exe /o="rcli.xml" /swea /x=ReSharper.StyleCop "my.sln"`

`inspectcode.exe /o="rcli.xml" /swea "my.sln"`

`inspectcode.exe /o="rcli.xml" /swea /x=ABCDEFG "my.sln"`

Result

> JetBrains Inspect Code 9.1.1
>
> Running in 64-bit mode, .NET runtime 4.0.30319.18444 under Microsoft Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
>
> Enabled solution-wide analysis according to Inspect Code command line Setting.
>
> Analyzing files
>
> *[files]*
>
> Inspection report was written to rcli.xml

**What am I doing wrong? How to get extensions to work?**

I already tried the [R# forums](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/466018), but it took them more then 24h to approve my post and so far I'm not sure someone else even read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the support for extensions was dropped in 9.0 due to the refactorings in the "ReSharper platform". I hope that JetBrains will bring it back soon.

See [RSRP-436208](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-436208).

Comment: Wow, having a command line switch that does not do anything... on purpose. That's a new low I would not have expected from JetBrains. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Oh, did not know I could. Logged in and did :)

Comment: Just a bit of context - it wasn't "dropped" as such, but it was due to the refactoring for the ReSharper Platform. 9.x changed the way ReSharper worked - instead of each product (ReSharper, dotCover, dotTrace, etc.) being a plugin to Visual Studio, we have a base VS plugin (the Platform) that in turn all the products plug into. This changed plugins from being dynamically loaded to statically registered (because VS needs this), and the command line tool expects to be able to load them dynamically. This mismatch hasn't been resolved yet.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think this limitation is no longer true in current R# version (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2):

This is a late answer that might help future readers (like myself). Currently `inspectcode.exe` will automatically look for and use any NuGet packages that are in the same folder as the executable ([source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/InspectCode.html#)).

Example for [CleanCode](https://github.com/MO2k4/CleanCode) extension:

- if you have a R# instance on some machine and install the extension, it will be placed in `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\plugins\MO.CleanCode.5.6.15`
- copy `MO.CleanCode.5.6.15.nupkg` and paste it next to `inspectcode.exe`
- when running inspectcode with verbosity = VERBOSE, the extension should appear in the `Zones` list:

  ```
  $cmd = "..\JetBrains.ReSharper.CommandLineTools.2019.3.4\inspectcode.exe" 
  $outputFile = "..\Output\$($outputName).xml"
  & $cmd -o="$outputFile" $sln --verbosity=VERBOSE
  ```

> Zones: (52pcs)[CodeInspectionPageImplZone, DaemonEngineZone,
>   DaemonZone, IAmd64CpuArchitectureHostZone, IAspMvcZone,
>   IBatchToolEnvironmentZone, IClrImplementationHost Zone,
>   IClrPsiLanguageZone, ICodeEditingOptionsPageImplZone,
>   IConsoleEnvironmentZone, ICppProductZone, ICpuArchitectureHostZone,
>   IDocumentModelZone, IEnvironmentZone,  IHostSolutionZone,
>   IInspectCodeConsoleEnvironmentZone, IInspectCodeEnvironmentZone,
>   IInspectCodeZone, ILanguageAspZone, ILanguageBuildScriptsZone,
>   ILanguageCppZone, I LanguageCSharpZone, ILanguageCssZone,
>   ILanguageHtmlZone, ILanguageIlZone, ILanguageJavaScriptZone,
>   ILanguageMsBuildZone, ILanguageNAntZone, ILanguageProtobufZone, ILa
>   nguageRazorZone, ILanguageRegExpZone, ILanguageResxZone,
>   ILanguageVBZone, ILanguageXamlZone, INetFrameworkHostZone, INuGetZone,
>   IOperatingSystemHostZone, IProjectMode lZone,
>   IPsiAssemblyFileLoaderImplZone, IPsiLanguageZone,
>   IPublicVisibilityZone, IRdFrameworkZone, IRiderModelZone,
>   ISinceClr2HostZone, ISinceClr4HostZone, ITextContro lsZone,
>   IToolsOptionsPageImplZone, IWebPsiLanguageZone, IWindowsNtHostZone,
>   PsiFeaturesImplZone, ReplaceableByIntelliJPlatformZone, SweaZone]
>   Packages: (23pcs)[JetBrains.ExternalAnnotations,
>   JetBrains.Platform.Core.Ide, JetBrains.Platform.Core.IisExpress,
>   JetBrains.Platform.Core.MsBuild, JetBrains.Platform. Core.Shell,
>   JetBrains.Platform.Core.Text, JetBrains.Platform.Interop.CommandLine,
>   JetBrains.Platform.Interop.dotMemoryUnit.Framework,
>   JetBrains.Platform.Interop.dotMe moryUnit.Interop.Console,
>   JetBrains.Platform.Interop.dotMemoryUnit.Interop.Ide,
>   JetBrains.Platform.RdProtocol, JetBrains.Psi.Features.Core,
>   JetBrains.Psi.Features.Cpp .Src.Core, JetBrains.Psi.Features.src,
>   JetBrains.Psi.Features.Tasks, JetBrains.Psi.Features.UnitTesting,
>   JetBrains.Psi.Features.Web.Core, JetBrains.ReSharperAutomatio
>   nTools.src.CleanupCode,
>   JetBrains.ReSharperAutomationTools.src.CommandLineCore,
>   JetBrains.ReSharperAutomationTools.src.CommandLineProducts,
>   JetBrains.ReSharperAutomat ionTools.src.DuplicatesFinder,
>   JetBrains.ReSharperAutomationTools.src.InspectCode, **MO.CleanCode**]

Comment: Upcoming 2020.3 version will bring back /x command line parameter to live.
Tools will download specified plugins automatically.